Create Sheets from list in excel using only one sheet as template
I'm using this code I copyed from old answer
Sub createSheet()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4")

    Dim wks As Worksheet


    For Each cell In rng
        On Error Resume Next
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            Set wks = Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count),Type:="C:\Users\PortlandRunner\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Template.xltx")
            wks.Name = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

Can path to template be to a specific sheet insade xltx file or does whole xltx needs to be template.
I want to my template to have data validation list and source for that list to be on diffrent sheet, but when I run code "data validation source sheet" is copyed as many times as my tamplete list and I only need 1

Why not use a template with only one sheet?

I hide my data for the data validation list in a sheet and use it like that, but I would like to have data in one sheet if I need to change it in the future so all the drop-down menus will change accordingly. I cannot create a data validation list with some name of a sheet that doesn't exist or delete a sheet and create it afterward couse excel changes the source name to some kind of error

You can use code to add the validation list after creating the sheet...
